# 304 Code on Scripts when viewed using Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

I am using 5 jquery plugins for my website. When I view the site on latest browsers, it runs smoothly but when I use Firefox, most of my scripts and even CSS transitions doesn't work anymore.I checked Firefox dev tool, FF received 304 code. Could it be that having too many jquerys causes this? Would the script be running even if the status code for that script is 304? 304 has something to do with the cache, right? I am confused now.

EDIT:

I am importing my JS files using Wordpress' wp_enqueue_scripts. I didn't post this question on wordpress.stack since I was suspecting the way FF handled javascript.

This is the whole function on my wordpress functions.

```
    function initScripts(){
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize',get_template_directory_uri().'/public/css/normalize.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('p-scrollbar','//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/0.5.7/perfect-scrollbar.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('typicons',get_template_directory_uri().'/public/css/typicons.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('fancybox-css',get_template_directory_uri().'/public/css/jquery.fancybox.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('dynamic',get_template_directory_uri().'/public/css/dynamic.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('main-required',get_stylesheet_uri());

    wp_enqueue_script('perfect-scrollbar','//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/0.5.7/perfect-scrollbar.min.js',array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.mousewheel.min',get_template_directory_uri().'/public/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js',array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.scroll.animate',get_template_directory_uri().'/public/js/jquery.scroll.animate.js',array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-scrollto',get_template_directory_uri().'/public/js/jquery-scrollto.js',array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui',get_template_directory_uri().'/public/js/jquery-ui.min.js',array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('fancybox',get_template_directory_uri().'/public/js/jquery.fancybox.js',array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('main-required-js',get_template_directory_uri().'/public/js/main.js',array('jquery'));
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','initScripts');
```

Comment: You should probably post how you're importing your scripts into your page.

Comment: `304 Not Modified` means the server is confirming Firefox already has the latest version of that resource, and doesn't need to reload it. This is almost certainly not your problem; Firefox should be loading things from cache just fine.

Comment: @Paul yeah just looks like a warning that FF throws that others don't. He's still saying that the scripts and transitions don't work. OP, for now assume the issues are unrelated - post some though, please!